# Should we encourage edit suggestions to be re-submitted until they are approved?

Tags: discussion

If an edit suggestion is rejected, is it acceptable for the user to re-submit an identical edit suggestion? I feel like this encourages a "mommy said no, so I'll get permission from daddy" situation that doesn't directly violate any policy, yet seems like an attempt to sidestep the moderation tools.

If an edit suggestion is rejected and the user feels it should have been accepted, shouldn't the user post to Meta instead?

Comment: I don't think most people realize their edits were rejected.  There's no notification for the fact.  And even if you go and find out that your edit got rejected it is usually not clear why it was rejected.  The lack of feedback for edits is regrettable.  Then eventually you get enough rep that your edits are instant and unreviewed.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, the edit suggestion should also be rejected the second time. Unless a moderator did it, I believe accept/reject still needs at least two people to click that button. That's one structural control to get around the two-parent problem. The reality is we have a small group of reliable editors, so the chances are very good that the second edit will be seen by one of the first rejectors and re-rejected.